# Aggregate MongoDB Nested Recursive Objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a data model that contains nested objects of the same kind:

```
{
  "name": "my-object",
  "section": {
    "type": "a",
    "files": [{
      "name": "file1.txt",
      "size": 87
    }, {
      "name": "file2.txt",
      "size": 726
    }],
    "subsections": [{
      "type": "b",
      "files": [{
        "name": "file3.txt",
        "size": 32
        }]
      }, {
      "type": "c",
      "files": [{
        "name": "file4.txt",
        "size": 567
      }],
      "subsections": [{
        "type": "d",
        "files": [{
          "name": "file4.txt",
          "size": 234
        }]
      }, ...]
    }]
  }
}
```

As you can see, the section object contains subsections, that also may have subsections and so on.

What I need is to be able to accumulate all the values for the field `size` on every entry of the `files` array for all the sections across all documents. For this example, I'd like to get the result `1646`.

I've tried using the aggregate command but I haven't been able to do this recursion. I might end up writing a js or python script that does this programmatically but I just wanted to validate first if there's a way to do it directly in Mongo.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this is a very nested structure which mongo will not be able to justify in a query. Have you explored an opportunity to simplify the structure of this data model?